# show/play video in gdoc

Tags: video, google-cloud-storage, google-docs

Is it possible to play a video/audios in google docs and originally the video/audio file is located in google cloud storage.

If so how I copy this video in gdoc and how I add an player option to play the video?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is no, you cannot do this.

You cannot insert direct videos in GDocs at all. [There are no options for this.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/97447) There *may* be third party extension that allow you to do so...